# Does C# has impact when evaluating /parsing expressions?

Tags: c#, .net

Sometimes back I was trying the following statement in C#

```
i+++++i // does not compile <bt>

i++ + ++i // executed
```

Does space has impact in expressions? 
In what way the above statements are different?

Ramachandran

Comment: Why on earth would you do that?

Comment: This is just to explore how a language interprets etc. may not be really useful in a real world application :)

Anyway thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First off, let me explain how a compiler works.

The first thing we do is break up the source code into *tokens*. Then we organize the tokens into a *parse tree*. Then we do a *semantic analysis* of the parse tree, and then we generate code based on that semantic analysis. Any of those stages - lexing, parsing or analyzing - can produce errors. Here's the important part: **we do not go back and re-do a previous stage if a later stage got an error**.

The lexer is "greedy" - it attempts to make the biggest token it can at every stage of the way. So Daniel is right. The lexer breaks i+++++i up into i / ++ / ++ / + / i

Then the parser tries to turn that into a parse tree and it comes up with

```
                +
               / \
              ++  i
             /
            ++
           /
          i
```

That is, equivalent to (((i++)++) + i).

Now the semantic analyzer looks at that and says "i++ is fine because i is a variable. But i++ is not a variable, it's a value. You cannot do ++ on a value, so the *second* ++ is illegal."  The semantic analyzer then gives the error: *the operand of an increment must be a variable*.

The semantic analyzer does **not** then re-do the lex and say you know, this could have been i / ++ / + / ++ / i, which would parse differently and be legal. We don't backtrack because there could be *billions* of possible ways to re-lex and re-parse a program and we don't want to have to try all of them. Just consider your case; i+++++i could be (((i++)++)+i) or )((i++)+(+(+i))) or (i+(+(+(+(+i)))) or... remember, + can be part of a unary plus, binary plus, pre-increment or post-increment, and therefore there are a *lot* of possible combinations for these five plusses.

Answer (score 10):

Spaces have an effect when separating tokens.

Obvious example: `int a = 1;` is not the same as `inta=1;`

Likewise, `+ +a` is the same as `+(+(a))`, which simply returns 1 (assuming `a=1`). However removing the space, the two `+` tokens will form a single `++` token, thus incrementing a to 2.

Your first example tokenized results in 5 tokens: "i" "++" "++" "+" "i"

Your second example results in slightly different 5 tokens: "i" "++" "+" "++" "i"

Answer (score 3):

C-ish (C/C++/C#/Java) compilers use a style of parsing called "max munch" -- They will always try to make the largest token possible.

Now, some characters automatically end a token -- a semicolon or a parenthesis for example.  And whitespace is one of them.

So, in your second example, then are 5 tokens: "i" "++" "+" "++" "i"

However, in your first example, there are only three: "i" "+++++" and "i"

Also, I should note that while your second example will compile under C++, it's completely illegal (you are not allowed to modify the same value twice in one statement).  It's probably illegal in C# also, though C# tends to be a bit more flexible on those things.

Comment: No, "+++++" is not a valid token in any C-ish language. Instead, his first example are 5 tokens: "i" "++" "++" "+" "i".

Comment: I didn't say it was a valid token, just a (parsed) token.

Comment: Daniel is right; this answer is incorrect. +++++ is not a token in C#. Instead, the tokenizer splits that up into i / ++ / ++ / + / i.

Comment: Also, the second form is perfectly legal C# and perfectly well-defined. There is no rule in C# that a variable cannot be mutated twice. There does not need to be such a rule because C# carefully defines the order of evaluation of subexpressions, unlike C/C++. These sorts of expressions are a bad idea in C/C++ because the order of evaluation is undefined and therefore there are multiple possible legal results.